# Using the generic type 'PX.Data.And2' requires 2 type arguments

Tags: acumatica

I'm defining a PXSelect for ARTran in a processing window:

//public PXSelect

//Equal>,

//And2,

//IsNull,

//Or

//Equal>>>>>>

//DetailsView;

But I keep getting this error...and need help.

\App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(18): error CS0305: Using the generic type 'PX.Data.And2' requires 2 type arguments
\App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(18): error CS0305: Using the generic type 'PX.Data.And2' requires 2 type arguments

Comment: public PXSelect<ARTran, Where<ARTran.customerID, Equal<Current<UpdateNotificationContactsFilter.customerID>>,
    And2<Where<Current<UpdateNotificationContactsFilter.contactID>, IsNull, Or<ARTranExt.usrContactID, Equal<Current<UpdateNotificationContactsFilter.contactID>>>>>>> DetailsView;

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is raised because the And2 class has only one generic type argument (Where) in your query:

```
And2<Operator<...>>
```

Where2/And2/Or2 requires two generic type argument in their prototype:

```
And2<Operator<...>, NextOperator<...>>
```

Your query Where clause can be split into two groups, first one is a single condition and the other one is 2 condition joined with an Or clause.

For this I prefer using Where2 over And2 like this:

```
Where2<Where<condition1>, And<condition2, Or<condition3>>>
```

For your query:

```
PXSelect<ARTran, 
Where<Where2<Where<ARTran.customerID, Equal<Current<UpdateNotificationContactsFilter.customerID>>>, 
             And<Current<UpdateNotificationContactsFilter.contactI‌​D>, IsNull, 
                 Or<ARTranExt.usrContactID, Equal<Current<UpdateNotificationContactsFilter.contactID>>>>>>>
```

Comment: \App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(20): error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
\App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(20): error CS1002: ; expected

Comment: \App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(20): error CS1519: Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
\App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(21): error CS1519: Invalid token '>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
\App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(21): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
\App_RuntimeCode\UpdateNotificationContacts.cs(20): error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected

Comment: public PXSelectJoin<ARTran,
    InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
        On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<ARTran.inventoryID>>>,
    Where<ARTran.customerID,   Equal<UpdateNotificationContactsFilter.customerID>>,
    OrderBy<Desc<ARTran.tranDate>>> DetailsView;

Comment: I was able to validate and publish this DetailsView for a processing page...however, when I click on the page or change one of the filters, I get an error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. "

Comment: If it says '>' expected then add '>' at the end of the query.

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. " , I think you removed Current<> around UpdateNotificationContactsFilter, this is needed.